# "Maximum update depth exceeded" on form validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do some form validation using React, to do this I'm using a NPM validator package and running the validator after my form component, but I'm getting an `Maximum update depth exceeded` error

My code:

```
 <Field>
          <Control>
            <Label>Epost</Label>
            <Input
              required
              name="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email input"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.handleEvent}
            />
            {validator.validate(email) ? (
              <Help color="success">
                <b>Correct email</b>
                {this.setState({ validEmail: true })}
              </Help>
            ) : (
              <Help color="danger">
                <b>Wrong email</b>
                {this.setState({ validEmail: false })}
              </Help>
            )}
          </Control>
        </Field>
```

Not sure where my error is, any ideas?

Comment: You're using `setState()` in your render function. That causes it to re-render, which causes that function to be called again, which triggers another re-render, and so on. `setState()` should be in response to something like a button click, or a HTTP request returning. It shouldn't be called during `render()`

Comment: You cannot setState inside render. You will need to create an update function, then reference that in your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the state "validEmail" after you validate it. Why don't you update it in the handleEvent instead of render it incorreclty?

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding an if else to my handleEvent
`  handleEvent = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    if (validator.validate(this.state.email)) {
      this.setState({ validEmail: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ validEmail: false });
    }
  };`

I also changed my condtional in render to only test for validEmail, but it's always set to false, even when the email is correct

Comment: I reloaded the server and now everything works as it should, should have checked that. Thank you for you help Danilo!

Answer (score 0):

My corrected code, thank you Danilo for your help:

```
 handleEvent = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    if (validator.validate(this.state.email) && this.state.validEmail !== "") {
      this.setState({ validEmail: true });
      console.log("korrekt epost");
    } else {
      this.setState({ validEmail: false && this.state.validEmail !== "" });
      console.log("ikke korrekt epost");
    }
  };
```

....

```
  <Field>
          <Control>
            <Label>Epost</Label>
            <Input
              required
              name="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email input"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.handleEvent}
            />
            {validEmail ? (
              <Help color="success">
                <b>Den epostadressen ser fin ut</b>
              </Help>
            ) : (
              <Help color="danger">
                <b>Det ser ut som det er noe galt med epostadressen du skrev</b>
              </Help>
            )}
          </Control>
        </Field>
```